# Server Side Include failing - non HTML coders needs assistance

Tags: apache2, centos

Good Afternoon,

I have a webserver that I am attempting to rebuild on behalf of a client, and I have a few bugs that I am trying to get out.

```
... <snipped from site>

</div> 
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--#include virtual="/includes/incfooter.shtml" -->
</body>
</html>

... <end of code>
```

At the bottom of each page, I have this refrence. Now my understanding is that teh webserver, apache in this case will replace that text with the contents of the file /includes/incfooter.shtml

To me, that looks like an absolute path, rather than a relative path, so I would really like to know where on my server I need to put this file!

```
<hair ripping out>
This is really getting me!
</hair ripping out>
```

Help please! :)

Comment: mod_include: Options +Includes (or IncludesNoExec) wasn't set, INCLUDES filter removed

I get the above warning in my log, but I have the following in my conf.d directory, (in a .conf file, thank you!) 


Options +Includes

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adjusting the permissions on the folders, I thought I did it earlier put I didn't